# Javascript : Compare two arrays and fill non matching elements with existing elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array1

```
var arr1 = ["27", "20", "18", "15", "14", "13", "8", "6", "2", "1"]
```

I have another array 2 which shows always from 1 to 30

```
var arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"]
```

I want to compare these two arrays and fill "NULL" in array1 for the rest of the values which are not present in array1

Basically my final array should display as

```
finalArray = ["1", "2", null, null, null, "6", null, "8", null, null, null, null, "13", "14", "15", null, null, "18", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "27", null, null, null]
```

Have tried looping 1st array inside 2nd array. But failing in pushing null values to the rest of the elements. How to achieve this? TIA

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. If you have already tried to solve this on your own then show your approach and explain the problems you have with it (including errors and a [mcve])

Comment: Also, do you want to change `arr1` in place, or leave `arr1` untouched and create a completely new array?

Comment: May I ask you why you would need `arr2`, if it is always going to contain numeric strings, ordered from `'1'` to `'30'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do the following by iterating over arr2 and check if the current item is inside arr1. If the item is inside arr1 you put the item in new array, otherwise put null,

```js
var arr1 = ["27", "20", "18", "15", "14", "13", "8", "6", "2", "1"]

var arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"]

res = arr2.map(item => arr1.includes(item) ? item : null);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a little different way.

First, create a `Map` using `arr1` then loop through the master array i.e., `arr2` and check if the value is present in the `Map`. If available use the same else fill it with null.

```js
var arr1 = ["27", "20", "18", "15", "14", "13", "8", "6", "2", "1"]

var arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"];

//Create a MAP using `arr1` so that while searching it'll be easy
let mappingObj = {};
arr1.forEach(val => {
  mappingObj[val] = val;
});

let res = arr2.map(val => mappingObj[val] || null)
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `arr2` always contains numeric strings, ordered from `'1'` to `'30'`, you do not even need to use it. You could do something like:

```js
const arr1 = ["27", "20", "18", "15", "14", "13", "8", "6", "2", "1"];

const finalArray = (new Array(30)).fill(null);

arr1.forEach(item => {
  finalArray[parseInt(item) - 1] = item;
});

console.log(finalArray);
```